# How to add slippage to a project when using Microsoft Project 2007?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2007

I have a plan with original dates that I would like to keep but then I have a project phase that is now delayed.  Are there recommended approaches when using Project 2007?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After an approved change, you can re-plan your next phase and strike a SECOND baseline. You can have multiple baselines in MSProject. Thus you can track your variances to several baselines.

Comment: Pity that project 2007 didn't make baseline management more obvious.